# Excel WEEKDAY formula doesn't recognise English Dates since I upgraded to Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an exisitng spreadsheet which was working fine, but after the upgrade all the dates in the sheet were converted to US form 6/27/2015. I was able to change them back to UK format but now this formula +WEEKDAY(A22,1) no longer returns a numeric value for day of the week I just get error messages.
If I change the date back in US format it works perfectly.